# Trigger current element where onclick event is define

Tags: javascript

I have a function like this. I want to select current element without passing parameter or change anything in HTML.

I see the `$(this)` is not working. Are there any other techniques we can achieve this?

```
function social_follow_us(){
    $(this).addClass("green")
}
```

HTML like this.

```
<a href="..." onclick="social_follow_us()" class="btn btn-primary followButton" target="_blank" id="instagram_follow">Follow on Instagram</a>
```

Comment: did you tried ```this.event``` in your function ?

Comment: No I haven't tired that

Comment: Given the code and the implied styling, it is likely the text won't change to the color green if that is the intent. If your link remains magenta/purple after trying some of these solutions, it is because you style must change the color of the `:visited` psuedo class, not just the base class.

Comment: Are you required to perform the task in `social_follow_us`?

Comment: yes. There are multiple follows and I want to pass class when success. This is just a small piece of code.

Comment: If you can't change the way the function is called from the HTML, you can't do it. There's no way for that kind of function to get the element that triggered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is to pass `this` from `<a onclick="...">`event:

```js
function social_follow_us(elem) {
  $(elem).addClass("green")
}
```

```css
a.green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="..." onclick="social_follow_us(this)" class="btn btn-primary followButton" target="_blank" id="instagram_follow">Follow on Instagram</a>
```

Comment: I actually doesn't want to change the parameter or change anything in HTML

Comment: @Santosh If you want the function to work on any element and you don't want to pass `this` from the html function call and mantain that way of invoking the function... I'm not sure it can be done.

Comment: It helped me anyway. I liked this approach. Thanks I learned something new.

Answer (score 0):

The context this is wrong it is the window object and not the  element you want to change color

```
function social_follow_us(){
  $(this).addClass("green")
} 

// try this
function social_follow_us(){
  $(".followButton").addClass("green");
}

// or
$('.followButton').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('green');
})
```